# mongo db sort by occurrences array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using Meteor. I want show a recommended items list in my page. I approach it finding user votes tags first and order them by occurrence.

```
var tags = [{name: 'tag1'},{name: 'tag2'},{name:'tag1'},{name: 'tag3'}];

tagsShortedByOccurrence = _(tags).chain().countBy('name').pairs().sortBy(1).pluck(0).value();

//tagsShortedByOccurrence will be like ..['tag1','tag2','tag3']
```

Now I want find items with that tags but sorted by tags array order. How I can do this?

Documents example:

```
//item document:
doc1 = {
     _id: 1,
     ....
     tags: [
         {name: 'tag1'},{name: 'tag2'}
     ]
}
doc2 = {
   _id: ,
   ....
   tags: [
     {name: 'tag2'},{name: 'tag3'}
   ]
}
```

var itemsRecommended = Items.find({...¿?},{limit: 1});

```
itemsRecommended = [{_id: 1}];
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have example code?

Comment: What do you mean by sorting by *array order*? Do you mean by *position* of a given tag in the array?

Comment: Yeah, Tags given in the array are sorted by priority.